# Resampling Pandas Series with integer index (add missing index)

Tags: python, pandas

I have Pandas Series like `s = pd.Series({1: 10, 2:11, 4:5, 7:10})`

```
1    10
2    11
4     5
7    10
dtype: int64
```

I would like to resample this serie in order to get a serie like that

```
1    10
2    11
3     0
4     5
5     0
6     0
7    10
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you got your serie from another programm/another part of your code, you could try:

```
max_range = max(s.index) + 1
s = s.reindex(index=range(1, max_range), fill_value=0)
```

Comment: You need to assign `s` to itself in order for the reindex to have an effect `s = s.reindex(index=range(1, max_range), fill_value=0)`